# Custom AccessDecisionManager doesn't get called on JPA repository method calls when not running locally

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

I've got a Spring Boot application using JPA repositories for db access.  By default, Spring builds a method interceptor with a default AccessDecisionManager, which contains voters which will decide whether users can access methods.

The default AccessDecisionManager contains a handful of voters and looks like this, in GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration.java:

```
protected AccessDecisionManager accessDecisionManager() {
    List<AccessDecisionVoter<? extends Object>> decisionVoters = new ArrayList<AccessDecisionVoter<? extends Object>>();
    ExpressionBasedPreInvocationAdvice expressionAdvice = new ExpressionBasedPreInvocationAdvice();
    expressionAdvice.setExpressionHandler(getExpressionHandler());
    if (prePostEnabled()) {
        decisionVoters
                .add(new PreInvocationAuthorizationAdviceVoter(expressionAdvice));
    }
    if (jsr250Enabled()) {
        decisionVoters.add(new Jsr250Voter());
    }
    decisionVoters.add(new RoleVoter());
    decisionVoters.add(new AuthenticatedVoter());
    return new AffirmativeBased(decisionVoters);
}
```

For our purposes, we needed to add a couple custom voters for method-level security.  According to the docs, we can override this method to do just that.  So, we created our own class called MethodSecurityConfig.java.  Its class signature looks like this:

```
@Slf4j
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, prePostEnabled = true)
public class MethodSecurityConfig extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration
```

This config class contains a single method, which overrides the method-level AccessDecisionManager:

```
@Override
protected AccessDecisionManager accessDecisionManager() {
    List<AccessDecisionVoter<? extends Object>> decisionVoters = new ArrayList<AccessDecisionVoter<? extends Object>>();
    ExpressionBasedPreInvocationAdvice expressionAdvice = new ExpressionBasedPreInvocationAdvice();
    expressionAdvice.setExpressionHandler(getExpressionHandler());

    decisionVoters.add(new PreInvocationAuthorizationAdviceVoter(expressionAdvice));
    decisionVoters.add(new RoleVoter());
    decisionVoters.add(new AuthenticatedVoter());
    decisionVoters.add(new CustomMethodVoter());
    return new AffirmativeBased(decisionVoters);
}
```

On app startup, we see this all execute beautifully.  Here's where it gets interesting.

When running the app *locally*, this all works perfectly.  Users are blocked from calling methods for which they are not authorized.  However, when running the app in our higher environments (dev, tst, etc.), none of those voters are called.

I enabled remote debugging on our dev box and it seems like I've figured out *what* isn't being called, but I don't understand *why* it's not being called.  On app startup, the custom AccessDecisionManager is built and it's even called on multiple occasions.

However, it's not *always* called.  The prime example is saving a new entity.  All our entities go through the same process of being validated (if necessary), then saved.  The code looks like this:

```
protected T validateAndSave(T entity) {
    validator.validateBeforeAnyCreateOrUpdate(entity)
    doAdditionalValidation(entity)
    repo.saveAndFlush(entity)
}
```

Here's what the saveAndFlush method looks like, using Spring Security's @Secured annotation:

```
@Secured([Roles.SOME_ENTITY_CREATE,Roles.SOME_ENTITY_UPDATE])
SomeEntity saveAndFlush(SomeEntity entity)
```

The custom AccessDecisionManager should call the RoleVoter, iterate through the method's roles, and compare them with the user's roles.  But this voter never gets called.

Locally, I'm able to see the general call stack that *does* result in the custom AccessDecisionManager being called.  After saveAndFlush is called, we end up in JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke().  One of the things that happens in this method is this:

```
List<Object> chain = this.advised.getInterceptorsAndDynamicInterceptionAdvice(method, targetClass);
```

Locally, this Proxy gets called *twice*.  The first time it's called, chain contains our custom method interceptor with all our voters.  The second time it's called, it contains a bunch of other interceptors that were added by RepositoryFactorySupport on app startup.

When running on our higher environments, this proxy only gets called *once*, and the interceptor chain only contains the interceptors added by RepositoryFactorySupport.  It doesn't get called again for the saveAndFlush call.

After many hours of remote debugging, I've not been able to figure out what's causing this.  My gut tells me that, since it's not consistent between our app running locally vs. our app running on dev, that it's a spring profile issue.  But I haven't been able to actually figure out *what* in the spring profiles could be causing this.

Here's a few specifics regarding the versions we're using:

- **openjdk**: 8u171
- **tomcat**: 8.5.32
- **docker image**: tomcat:8.5.32-jre8-alpine
- **springBootVersion**: 1.4.2.RELEASE
- **groovy**: 2.4.7

I realize this issue is sort of annoying and nebulous and it all looks like a red herring, or a symptom of a totally different problem.  So honestly I'm looking for any advice for what else I could do to even try to figure out what the problem *actually* is.

Thanks for reading.